# elasticsearch-dsl - from_dict

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to move to `elasticsearch-dsl` and port my old `dict/json` like
queries to `elasticsearch-dsl` syntax.

The `from_dict` method seems to do the job, but I would like to see the
new syntax.

I do not see any attribute of `from_dict` that would print it. I would like to get (see) output like the below from the dict query

```
Search(using=client, index="my-index") \
.filter("term", category="search") \
.query("match", title="python")   \
.query(~Q("match", description="beta"))"
```

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use `repr` on the resulting `search.query._proxied` you will get the new syntax, just not iteratively constructed like you have it here but instead how it would look if you'd constructed it directly, something like:

`Bool(filter=[Term(category='search')], must=[Match(title='python')], must_not=[Match(description='beta')])`

I will make a note to make this easier since the `._proxied` is definitely not intuitive, no documented :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect,Thank you